# wordpress head is empty, append to body

Tags: wordpress, heading

I'm have a problem for Wordpress heading. my get_header();

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
<title>
<?php wp_title('&laquo;', true, 'right'); ?>
<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>
</title>
<meta name="language" content="tr-TR" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="location" content="türkiye, tr, turkey" />
<meta name="robots" content="all" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS 2.0" href="<?php bloginfo('rss2_url'); ?>" />
<link rel="alternate" type="text/xml" title="RSS .92" href="<?php bloginfo('rss_url'); ?>" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" title="Atom 0.3" href="<?php bloginfo('atom_url'); ?>" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/style.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/fa/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/eiddia.js" type="text/javascript"/></script>
<!--[if gte IE 9]>
  <style type="text/css">
    .gradient {
       filter: none;
    }
  </style>
<![endif]-->
<?php wp_head();?>
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```

The Result 
[image]

Comment: can u please show your header.php ??

Comment: I shared above header.php.